# Scrollpagination plugin in symfony

Tags: jquery, symfony, scroll-paging

i'm trying since three hours to fix the problem (Symfony 2.2) but i didn't find any solution.i don't know how to write the url of a page in contentpage:

```
$('#container_sub_ejob').scrollPagination({
            'contentPage': '/tts/list', 
            .......
        });
```

in my routing i wrote :

```
tts_show:
    pattern:  /tts/list
    defaults: { _controller: bgsBundle:bgs:show }
```

and controller:

```
public function showAction()
    {
        return $this->render('bgsBundle:bgss:all_content.php');
    }
```

Comment: Symfony 2.4 does not exist (yet). The latest release of Symfony is version 2.2, with 2.3 currently unstable & under active development.

Comment: mistake sorry, i corrected it